# What is the difference between IoT devices and Iot Edge?

Tags: azure

i would like to know what is the difference between creating a device through "IoT devices" and "IoT Edge". I would like to connect my ESP32 to my Azure IoT Service so which one to choose?

Answer (score 3):

An IoT Edge device lets you run computing on the edge in form of modules in docker containers. This can be azure modules which is provided by Microsoft or other custom modules that you develop. IoT edge also lets you handle the whole deployment process directly from the IoT Hub.

A regular IoT Device is much simpler where you provide an connection string in your code and use this to send your messages to the cloud from the device. It`s also possible to maintain state by using device twins for settings e.g. desired properties like how often you should send messages to the cloud and so on.

It`s not quite clear what you are trying to achieve by saying "Azure IoT Service". There is an Azure IoT Hub Service SDK which you can use to interact with the IoT Hub and do things like list, create and edit devices.. If you are planning to just send messages to the cloud from some device a regular IoT device will provide the things you want.